# Collect String to LinkedHashMap <Character, Integer> , with frequency of characters

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I need to collect a sentence to a map using stream, where the key is a character (the order should be like this: the first letter in the sentence is the first in the map, so I choose LinkedHashMap ), and the value is counter which shows the frequency of repeating the same character.

> Example input: hello world

> Example output: h=1 , e=1, l=3, o=2, w=1 , r=1, d=1

There is my code, and I can`t understand what is the problem.

```
private Map<Character, Integer> countSymbols(String sentence) {
    return sentence.chars()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> (Character) key, 
                    counter -> 1, 
                    Integer::sum, 
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: `chars()` return an `IntStream` which doesn’t have a `collect(Collector)` method. Use `.chars().mapToObj(i -> (Character)i)` to get a `Stream<Character>`. Then, you don’t need a type cast in `toMap`.

Comment: If you are okay with `Map<Character, Long>` you can also just use `Collectors.counting()`. Super simple, compact and readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.chars()` returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) (i.e., a stream of primitieve `int`s), that can't be collected with `Collectors.toMap`.

You could map it to a `Character` object, and once you've done so, you could use `Collectors.grouping` to do the heavy lifting instead of implementing its logic:

```
private Map<Character, Long> countSymbols(String sentence) {
    return sentence.chars()
                    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                                   Collectors.counting()));
}
```

**EDIT:**

`Collectors.grouping` does not retain the order of the stream, so you'll really have to implement it manually as you've done.
the `mapToObj` call is still required, and if you want to avoid counting the space between "hello" and "world" in the example, you need to add a `filter` call:

```
private Map<Character, Integer> countSymbols(String sentence) {
    return sentence.chars()
                   .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
                   .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                            counter -> 1,
                            Integer::sum,
                            LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: Just a note, this solution uses a `Map<Character, Long>` and not `Integer`, due to `Collectors.counting()`.